# Use jQuery masonry with Absolutely Positioned Parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I have a dropdown (ul.sub-menu) with items inside (ul.sub-menu > li) that I'd like to apply jQuery Masonry to, but my dropdown is absolutely positioned.  Is there a way to do this and keep my absolute positioning on the parent element?

**Javascript**

```
jQuery("ul > li > ul.sub-menu").masonry({
  itemSelector: '.brick',
  columnWidth: 300
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li id="menu-item-9451" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9451"><a href="/solutions/" >Solutions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-9458" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/internal-social-software/" >Internal Social Software</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9457" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/video-content-managment/" >Video Content Managment</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9456" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/enterprise-content-management/" >Enterprise Content Management</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9455" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/secure-file-sharing/" >Secure File Sharing</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9454" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/redaction-and-document-viewing/" >Redaction and Document Viewing</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9453" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/real-time-business-intelligence/" >Real Time Business Intelligence</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9452" class="brick"><a href="/solutions/mobile-enterprise-applications/" >Mobile Enterprise Applications</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Masonry settings try:

```
containerStyle: { position: 'absolute' }
```

[See docs on `containerStyle`](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#containerstyle)

By default, Masonry sets `position: relative` on the container.