# Masonry float:left & max-width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

```
<style>

#container {
  float: left;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.item {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
}

</style>

<div id="container">

  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>
  <div class="item">Much of Text</div>

</div>
```

I get Mansory working in all situations great:

- with applied to `#container` `max-width` property alone
- and `float: left` alone

But sadly it is not working if apply combo of both `float: left` & `max-width`.

1. How to make it working this way and why it is getting not working
   after applying both CSS properties?
2. I need float `#container` to the left and in the same time need to
   have `max-width` on it. Is there any possibility to do it somehow? I
   tried use float: left on container's parents but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Masonry *#container* must be positioned relative, the *.masonry-brick* elements are positioned absolute by the layout engine - that's the whole point about Masonry working out the positioning of elements automatically. If you change the positioning of the *.masonry-brick* elements yourself, you're putting a spanner in the works. See [the documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and the many examples out there. To change the position of the *#container*, just observe other examples with Chrome's devtools to see how with preceding elements, margins and padding you can put it where you want.

Comment: The point is that I don't change .masonry-brick positioning. I only want to change #container to having `float: left` in the same moment with `max-width`. Why do these two properties in a combo make Masonry not working?

Comment: Have a look at the original plugin code https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.js where you can see that, in order to work, the plugin sets the position of the #container to relative. This is because the .masonry-brick elements need to have position absolute to be layouted the way they are - which is the whole purpose of that plugin. Why do you think for your layout you need to float the #container? Quite possibly, your layout can be achieved by other means. But that's another question where one would have to see how your page layout is supposed to look like.

Comment: See http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ for why relative positioning of a div is necessary for absolute positioning of divs contained therein.

Comment: Are you trying to say that `float: left` cancels relative positioning of `#container`? What on the matter does `float: left` with `position` property? Because it's a little confusing for me here.

Comment: Yes, you are conflicting with the plugin. Try for yourself with Chrome's devtools on the Masonry site by adding `float: left` to the #container element.style and rezize the browser window.

Comment: The #container does not have to be positioned relative, [there's an option to change it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9996413/243925).