# positioning divs below each other

Tags: html, css, positioning

imagine I have 6 divs in a parent div  and if I use inline-block It will show up like this
[image: inline divs]

but I want to them two show up like this.
[image: divs below each other]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Masonry float:left & max-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240917/masonry-floatleft-max-width)

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately....

This isnt possible using vanilla HTML and CSS (sorry).

You will need to use a JS library like [**isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/), or write your own javascript layout manager.

### Clarification- CSS columns wont work

There has been downvoting of this answer on the wrongful assumption that this can be accomplished with a column layout using `column-count`. This is not the case. Columns order top to bottom, not left to right then a new line.

### [This can be clearly seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMXkF/)

Where the elements are ordered vertically, and do not follow the numbering convention noted in the question.

Comment: what about using columns ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: @ProllyGeek - columns do vertical ordering, the OP is after horizontal

Comment: doesnt look he is after horizontal !!

Comment: doesn't look OP is after horizontal alignment to me either.

Comment: @ProllyGeek, the numbering the OP provided goes from left to right then a new line, columns go top to bottom then a new column.

Comment: @TJ - see comment above, the numbers the OP provided are not in columns, but in nested rows.

Comment: @ProllyGeek - you must also recognise this having not added columns to your answer?

Comment: @SW4 The op just wanted to remove gaps between div in a single column.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Not sure what you are saying re votes. Please provide a columns example.

Comment: Why a column layout is not appropriate: http://jsfiddle.net/qMXkF/ you can see in the OP numbering vs the col numbering

Comment: @ProllyGeek - look at the numbers in the question, they go 1->2 from left to right. In your example, they go top to bottom, columns change the order of the elements from that which the OP wants.

Comment: @SW4 The OP issue was not the numbers !! was it ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek - you've changed the layout from the one which the OP provided. Any solution should match what was asked for. Ask yourself this- if the numbers were not important why were they explicitly included?

Comment: this not just easily showing divs in static page. user can swap divs. user can extend height of each div and add or delete and All of those are animated.Using two columns is not the case because a tall div in first column will not push all of divs to the next column. I tried mansory and but it has conflict with my other codes. Now I am just confused and thinking about writing something on my own witch can take too many hours.

Answer (score 1):

this is called mansory , check these may help you :

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://desandro.github.io/masonry/

no need to provide code , cause this question has been asked here so many times , im just giving you the key to search for.

this may help as well :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/hP6fS/

```
side1=0,side2=0
$(".flexbox").children().each(function(index, element) {
if(side1<=side2)
{
$(this).css("top",side1+"px") 
side1+=parseInt($(this).css("height"))
}
else if(side2<side1)
{
$(this).css("top",side2+"px")
$(this).css("left","50%") 
side2+=parseInt($(this).css("height"))
}

});
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]No Javascript, No Jquery = Just Simple CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/6hx63x9x/1/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"> <div class="box1"><span class="big-font">1</span></div> <div class="box2"><span class="big-font">2</span></div> <div class="box3"><span class="big-font">3</span></div> <div class="box4"><span class="big-font">4</span></div> <div class="box5"><span class="big-font">5</span></div> <div class="box6"><span class="big-font">6</span></div> </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{ width:250px; float:left; height:auto; border:1px solid #5694cf;} .big-font {font-size:40px;color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; font-family:verdana;} .box1{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:150px;line-height: 150px; float:left; display:table;} .box2{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:50px; float:right;display:table-cell;} .box3{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:150px; line-height: 150px;float:right;display:table-cell;} .box4{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:100px; line-height: 100px;float:left; display:table;} .box5{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:50px; float:right;display:table-cell;} .box6{min-width:100px; border:1px solid #000; background:#5694cf;text-align: center;margin:10px;height:100px; line-height: 100px;float:left; display:table-cell;}
```